# Htaccess Login e Senha

Tags: php, htaccess, apache

Estou com um problema, tenho um diretorio de diferentes arquivos do tipo csv, xls, pdf, docx... Eu queria que a pessoa.h que colocasse no navegador o link do arquivo não tivesse acesso a ele, apenas aqueles que fizeram o acesso pela pagina de login tivessem o acesso.
Como faço isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer isso, você irá criar um sistema de autenticação (bem parecido com sistema de login).

Ex Basico:

```
<?php

if($_GET['url'] == 'arquivo'){
   if(!$_SESSION['login']['auth']){
       echo '<input type="text" name="email"><input type="password" name="senha">';
   }
}
```

A logica inicial é essa, mas você tem que evoluir para algo mais complexo, utilizar `Hash` e etc.

.htaccess

```
<Directory /caminho> 
    Options -Indexes 
</Directory>
```

Comment: Mas como eu bloqueio o acesso aos arquivos?

Comment: Eu já tenho a página de login dessa maneira

Comment: Você vai bloquear acesso direto aos arquivos via URL, dessa maneira irá exibir os arquivos utilizando PHP. Vou atualizar o codigo, mostrando como fazer bloqueio com htaccess

Comment: Certo, já conheço isso, mas não resolve o problema, exemplo: localhost/files/arquivo.pdf, quem digitar isso tem acesso ao arquivo. Mas eu queria que só aqueles que possuem a sessão de acesso tenham o acesso a ele